# Cannot delete user profile created on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, user-profiles

I created an account on Windows Server. But the problem comes when i want to delete the user profile. I have tried deleting it from Control Panel -> Advanced Settings -> Users -> Delete the profile.

It disappears from the Users list. But it still exists in C:\>Users directory. On a further note, i also remove the account from the Control Panel -> Users Management.

Is it normal or abnormal....???

Comment: is this a local user or did you set this windows server 2008 install up as a domain controller?   If it is not a domain controller, is it on a windows network with a domain controller, or is this strictly a local account?   Is the account 'guest' or 'administrator'?  Do you have administrative rights over this machine?   Did you add the user via Control Panel > Advanced > Users?

Comment: Instead of adding *Solved* to the title, please answer your own question by using the button below. You can then accept this answer in two days.

Comment: @Richie086, slhck - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure i have used to delete the profile is:

1. Navigate to the control panel -> Users Accounts -> Give other users access to this computer , select the user and remove.
2. Navigate to the control panel -> In the search box, type "advanced" -> Under System choose View Advanced System Settings. Select the user profile and Delete.

The profile is now not listed in the C:\>Users directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd delete the c:\users directory after you are sure that the account has been removed from the users.

Comment: thanks for your response. Soon after posting the question, i was able to delete the profile. Just i have to remove it from the advanced user profile settings.

Comment: Sounds good....M$ has a way of changing the place to go on things between releases.  Its a pain as I know what I want to do just not where it is hidden.  Like the power off in Windows 8 for example. :-)

Comment: loll...true. I agree.:)